# AS3 Find MC path on mouseClick?

Tags: actionscript-3

Is there a way to get the path to the movieClip I'm clicking?

e.g. event.currentTarget.path? (This doesn't work but I'd like something like it!)

Thanks

Comment: you can write a recursive function that checks if event.CurrentTarget has a parent and appends it to a list/path. Still if will be handy to name your DisplayObjects, otherwise it will be a bit tricky, unless you know your way around the project @grapefrukt I think he means the path from the top of the display list to the movie clip being clicked

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza - yes, I mean from the top of the display list. Is this possible? Seems like it should be easy but can't find a way to do it

Comment: if you're using Flash, the easiest option is to go to **Debug>List Objects(CMD+L / Ctrl+L)** when you test your movie and if you have something like `trace(event.currentTarget.name);` you should be able find it in the listed hierarchy. HTH

Comment: You can try make loop through parent's DisplayObjectContainers , var object:DisplayObject = e.currentTarget ; var path:String = "" ; while(object != stage){path += object.name ;object = object.parent}; trace(path);

Comment: @turbosqel, that code worked with a little tweaking. Thanks. But can't mark as answered from comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So You like to gain path by names :]

Here You have working version , before i write only idea .

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN , mouseHandler);

public function mouseHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
    var object:DisplayObject = e.target as DisplayObject;
    var path:String = object.name ;
    while(object != e.target.root){
            object = object.parent;
            path = object.name + "." + path;
            trace(object);
    };
    trace("stage."+path);
};
```

To get DisplayObject by path im using this function : [link to github](https://github.com/turbosqel/as3SupportLib/blob/master/as3SupportLib/src/UDisplay.as#L262)

Comment: I like to gain path by names? Yes, can you suggest a better way? (You're example works, of course.)

Comment: I think there is no better way than this . You can only loop through parent object and get its name or depth .

Answer (score 1):

If by path you mean a string representation of a displayobject's path in the display list you can use recursion to build a path string like the following:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            var sprite1:Sprite = new Sprite();
            sprite1.name = "sprite1";
            var sprite2:Sprite = new Sprite();
            sprite2.name = "sprite2";
            var sprite3:Sprite = new Sprite();
            sprite3.name = "sprite3";

            stage.addChild(sprite1);
            sprite1.addChild(sprite2);
            sprite2.addChild(sprite3);

            trace(getPath(sprite3));

        }

        private function getPath(displayObject:DisplayObject):String
        {
            var path:String = "";

            var name:String = (displayObject != stage) 
                ? displayObject.name : "stage";

            path += name + ".";

            if (displayObject.parent)
            {
                path = getPath(displayObject.parent) + path;

            }

            return path;

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package
```