# How to get the full resource path from a child control?

Tags: actionscript-3, graphics, resources

I am a new to Action Script, so I am not sure if my question is meaningless. But, please try to give some suggestion :-).

Currently, I have a requirement need to get the full resource path in runtime, **IF POSSIBLE**.

Here is an example: I have a action script and using a MovieClip resource. Now, I have a action script variable `ctrlVar` that is pointing to a child control , whose id is, for example, `contorl1`. And the real path I can find from fla file should be, for example, `parent1.parent2.parent3.control1`. And every `parentX` is a id ( not a type ).

I want to know, if it is possible, how can I generate the `parent1.parent2.parent3.control1` from `ctrlVar` in **runtime**?

Thanks.

Comment: Jackson's answer is good. Very similar to your issue, you should have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9697829/as3-find-mc-path-on-mouseclick)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question fully, but maybe this will help:

```
function locationOf(obj:DisplayObject):String {
    var loc:String;
    loop:
    while(obj.parent) {
        loc ? loc = "." + loc : loc = "";
        loc = obj.name + loc;
        try {
            obj = obj.parent;
        } catch(e:Error) {
            return loc;
        }
    }

    return loc;
}
```

That will let you know the dot-path of the object you're currently running code on.

Comment: I forget to tell the fact that I am using action script2, but when I replace "parent" and "name" to "_parent" and "_name", it works well here. Thanks very much for you help.~